# Should I be using a C# namespace for simple console apps?

Tags: c#, namespaces, projects-and-solutions

I'm new to C#, and am curious about best practice for using namespaces.

I have a solution that contains a single class library project, along with several, small console app projects.  All the console app projects do is parse command-line arguments and call different classes within the library project.  The library project uses the standard CompanyName.Tool convention.

My question is, since the only purpose of a given console app is to a class in the library project, and will never itself be called from another project or class, do I need to put it inside a namespace?  It seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct.  It is unnecessary.  The only reason you would want to be using a namespace is if you are creating libraries for re-use in many programs.

Answer (score 3):

No, you dont need to.  I find it's easier for maintainability to keep the entry points of an app (console, web, or windows) without namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

The project will have a default namespace if you look in the properties.  Any class not given an explicit namespace will inherit that one.  So you don't need a namespace for any class unless it differs from the project one.